# Why no gravity lens around planets?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, planets, gravitational-lensing

If large mass causes a curvature around spacetime, then why don't we see a gravity lens around our planets?

Comment: Did you try to calculate the magnitude of the effect?

Comment: I don't know about physics and calculations. It's just an open question to learn more.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: Historical side-note: Einstein originally wanted experimentalists to measure light lensing around Jupiter to support GR. But, then when he did the calculations he found out that the amount of lensing would be too small to be detected then.

Comment: Since the premise of the question has been debunked (there _is_ lensing). Perhaps you could change the title/content? (e.g., How much gravitational lensing is there around the planets?/Is gravitational lensing around planets detectable?, etc.)

Comment: @OscarBravo: Answers should not rewrite questions, it defeats the purpose of keeping the question around. Question correction is independent of whether answers have been given and what those answers may contain.

Comment: Related at Astronomy.SE: [Can the Earth be used as a gravitational lens?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36756/735)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Contrary to the other answers, I will point out that gravitational lensing due to planets in the solar system is a significant and measurable effect. The measured positions of stars, as seen from a point in the solar system near the Earth are altered by the gravitational deflection due to the fields of the Sun and then, in order of decreasing effect, Earth Jupiter, Saturn, Venus, Uranus, Neptune.

The size of the effect depends on the angular separation of a star from the solar system object and can be anything from 0 to 70 microarcseconds.

This sounds very small, but is *easily* within the precision of positional measurements by the [Gaia spacecraft](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/home). In fact, the effects of these deflections *have* to be taken into account in order to provide accurate positions as intermediate data for the calculation of the parallaxes and proper motions of stars.

A brief [information sheet](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/documents/29201/310761/IN_light_bending.pdf/49288d09-e584-43ab-b3bb-237c3ed5f114) on the topic has been produced by ESA.

However, this lensing and these kinds of deflections are not strong enough to produce multiple images or Einstein rings. The angular size of a perfect Einstein ring is given by
$$\theta_E \simeq \left[ \left(\frac{4GM}{c^2}\right) \frac{D_{LS}}{D_L D_S}\right]^{1/2} \ 
 ,$$
where $M$ is the mass of the lens, $D_L$ is the distance from observer to lens, $D_S$ is the distance to the source and $D_{LS}$ is the distance between the lens and the source. Since in this case $D_{S} \gg D_{L}$ and $D_{S} \simeq D_{LS}$, then
$$\theta_E \simeq  \left(\frac{4GM}{c^2D_L}\right)^{1/2}  = 0.071 \left(\frac{M}{M_{\rm Earth}}\right)^{1/2} \left( \frac{D_L}{1{\rm AU}}\right)^{-1/2}\ {\rm arcsec}$$

Taking Jupiter as an example, this yields $\theta_E \sim 0.6$ arcsec. But this is a lot smaller than the angular diameter of the planet ($\sim 50$ arcsec). In other words, to see multiple images or rings you would need to be *much* further away from Jupiter than a few AU and a star that is directly behind Jupiter is completely hidden when viewed from the Earth.

Comment: It might be worth adding for OP that not only do planets produce lensing effects, this is one of the ways we detect exoplanets (Wikipedia claims we've found 89 exoplanets this way).

Comment: @tfb This method of detecting exoplanets does not use lensing effects of the exoplanet, but instead looks for aberrations that an exoplanet causes on lensing *by its parent star* of a more distant star or galaxy.

Comment: @gandalf61 wouldn't those aberrations be due to the fact that the planet is interfering by way of its own lensing?

Comment: The point is that you are not directly detecting the [IMPOSSIBLY TINY] lensing of the planet. You are detecting a fluctuation in an (BARELY ACCESSIBLE TINY) lensing effect of the parent star.

Comment: Furthermore the magnitude of the "lensing effect" in play here is not as dramatic increasing the size of a remoter image, such as has happened with galaxy-level lensing. The effect is "Hey, that remoter star beyond the star of interest should have hit pixel (44,44) in this image but it actually hit (45,44).  Different than yesterday. Maybe an expolanet."

Comment: @RossPresser the perturbation in the lensing signature (in this case is a magnification and positional shift) *is* due to the exoplanet. However this question was about "our planets".

Comment: @gandalf61: Detecting a perturbation in the  lensing caused by a star *is* detecting the lensing caused by a planet.  Saying otherwise is like saying that detecting small perturbations to Newtonian predictions of the orbit of Mercury is not detecting effects due to GR: it is.  However, as Rob Jeffries says this is a question about Solar system planets, so perhaps not relevant to it.

Comment: @gandalf61 - your comment is not correct. Detection of extrasolar planets through gravitational microlensing is done through an increase in the measured luminous flux in a particular way, specifically due to the mass of the extrasolar planet.

Comment: Hello! I am currently tring to understand how you got from 
$\theta_E \simeq  \left(\frac{4GM}{c^2D_L}\right)^{1/2}$  to $0.071 \left(\frac{M}{M_{\rm Earth}}\right)^{1/2} \left( \frac{D_L}{1{\rm AU}}\right)^{-1/2}\ {\rm arcsec}$. Where did the AU come from, and what about $c^2$? (This is in no way to question the validity and correctness of your answer, I simply want to understand how you got there. I am still in school and have never done this before, so I might have missed something that was important for this step).

Comment: @Jonas this is a common trick when you want to put things in natural sized units. Simply insert $M$ as an Earth mass in kg and $D_L$ as 1 AU in metres into the first equation, and you will get 0.071 arcsec. For any other mass and distance then it scales appropriately.

Answer (score 15):

The deflection angle for a light ray that is just grazing the surface of a planet or star (so the maximum observable deflection) is

$\displaystyle \theta = 2 \left( \frac {v_e} {c} \right)^2$

where $\theta$ is in radians, $v_e$ is the escape velocity of the planet or star and $c$ is the speed of light (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens)). For a planet, $\frac {v_e}{c}$ is too small for this deflection to be detected. You need an escape velocity of hundreds of km/s to produce a measurable deflection of light, so this requires something as massive as a star or as compact as a black hole.

Correction:

Ok, so deflections of light rays by planets in the Solar System *can* be detected by space based instruments such as Gaia. But to get a lens effect (i.e. multiple images) you need to be far enough away from the planet that the planet's angular diameter is less than twice the maximum deflection. So we are too close to any planet in the Solar System to see it cause multiple images of a distant object due to gravitational lensing.

Comment: I would just like to note that it is possible to see even small deflection angles, but you need to be very far away. That is how e.g. galaxies end up being effective lenses.

Comment: The angle of deflection is detected and is routinely measured and corrected for. Neither is this the reason specifically that gravitationally lensed images are not seen.

Answer (score 4):

The effect is proportional to mass and it takes a big galaxy to see it. A big  galaxy has typically a mass of $10^{11} $ solar masses so about $3\cdot10^{17} $ Earth masses. The angle of deflection is incredibly small for a planet.

Comment: I do love the typo   "soNar" masses :-)

Comment: The angle of deflection is small but can be, and is, measured.

Comment: It's not just the mass but also the density that matters. A black hole a tiny fraction of a galaxy's size can cause more lensing.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a red herring.  There is this effect around all bodies.  It is probably very weak and therefore not likely to make a significant impact of local observations.  "Lensing" is the result of distorted ray paths and ALL sources of gravity will distort ray paths.  The issue is whether this will be noticeable over short distances.

Comment: Based on false assumptions? Yes. But a red herring? To my understanding, a red herring deliberately misleads. Anyway, it's well possible that there some nuances of the real-world use of the term I just don't get, for I'm not an English native speaker.

Comment: The term "red herring" can and is often applied to cases where false info is inadvertently provided but you are correct that perhaps the original and more prevalent use is in describing an intentionally misleading piece of info.  I use the term in the more loose sense (presence of false info even inadvertent).  Was not my intent to accuse the OP of intentional misleading.